# Select referenced range from non-active table via VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Given a certain range `rngRange` e.g. `set rngRange = Workbooks(2).Worksheets(5).Range("C4:P49")` If I use `rngRange.select` it will throw an error message if the table containing the range is not the active window/workbook/table (e.g. by `wbWorkbook.Activate` and `wsWorsheet.Activate`). Using `rngRange.Activate` by itself doesn't work (throws an error), probable a simple problem. But somehow I'm blind today.

Is it possible to "activate" the range directly without activating the workbook/worksheet first? And if not, can I get a workbook/worksheet reference from the range reference somehow (note, the whole thing is inside a function that only gets the range reference, I would like to avoid to add a wbWorkbook/worksheet reference since I have to change all function calls as well)?

Comment: `rngRange.Parent` will reference the worksheet where `rngRange` is. And `rngRange.Parent.Parent` will reference the workbook.

Comment: You might try the Application.Goto  Workbooks(2).Sheets(5).Range("C4:P49") to select (or with the range Application.Goto rngRange )

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Peh that's what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @Viktor Application.Goto rngRange works as well, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rngRange.Parent 'gives you the sheet
rngRange.Parent.Parent 'gives you the workbook
```

So you can use them to `.Activate` them.

```
rngRange.Parent.Parent.Activate
rngRange.Parent.Activate
rngRange.Select
```

---

Alternatively as @Viktor mentioned:

```
Application.Goto rngRange
```